# Why is this the right way to transform probability distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On [this site](https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Monte_Carlo_Integration/Transforming_between_Distributions) it is discussed how to get the probability distribution from a transformed distribution. If a continuous variable $X$ has a probability density function $p_X(x)$ and a second variable is defined as $Y=y(X)$, then we are interested to find $p_Y(y)$. In the link they use the following argument:

> The function $y(x)$ must be a one-to-one transformation; if multiple values
> of $x$ mapped to the same  value, then it would be impossible to
> unambiguously describe the probability density of a particular $y$ value.
> A direct consequence of $y$ being one-to-one is that its derivative must
> either be strictly greater than 0 or strictly less than 0, which
> implies that

$$Pr\left\{Y\leq y(x)\right\}=Pr\left\{X\leq x\right\}$$

I don't understand how this last equation follows from the requirement that $y(x)$ must be one-to-one. Does anyone know how to make this step?

Comment: "if multiple values of x
 mapped to the same value, then it would be impossible to unambiguously describe the probability density of a particular y
 value." - This statement is completely wrong. There are many instances where you can obtain the density of $Y$ without the transformation being one-to-one. See for instance theorem 4.2 in https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Note, that being one-to-one implies that the transformation is either increasing or decreasing. If $y$ is increasing, then
$$X \leq x \Leftrightarrow y(X) \leq y(x),$$
which follows directly from the definition of what an increasing function is. However it could also be the case that $y$ is decreasing in which case we would have
$$X \leq x \Leftrightarrow y(X) \geq y(x).$$
Thus in general if $y$ is one-to-one, then we have either
$$P(Y\leq y) = P(X \leq x) \quad \text{ or } \quad P(Y\leq y) = P(X\geq x).$$

Comment: This cleared things up a lot for me. The equation $X\leq x\iff y(X)\leq y(x)$ is what was missing from my understanding.